# Apresentação de frações no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, formatação

Acho que dá para ficar um pouco melhor do que fiz.

> 7. Faça um algoritmo que calcule e apresente a soma dos 30 primeiro
>    termos da série:
>
> 480 -  475 + 470 -  465 ...        10   11    12     13      (isso são
> frações, respectivamente com numerador e denominador, mas nem aqui
> consegui representá-las)

Na minha resolução as saídas ficaram assim:

> ```
> O numerador da fração 01 é: 475
> O denominador da fração 01 é: 11
> Com sinal: Negativo
> ```

mas queria de forma mais objetiva apresentando a fração em si com o sinal, mas não achei nenhuma forma, meu código é o seguinte:

```js
var numerador = 480
    var denominador = 10
    var sinal = "Positivo"
    for(i=0;i<=29;i++){
        numerador-=5
        denominador++
        if(sinal=="Negativo"){
            sinal = "Positivo"
        }else{
            sinal = "Negativo"
        }
        console.log("O numerador da fração " + i+1+" é: "+ numerador+"\nO denominador da fração " + i + 1 + " é: " + denominador+"\nCom sinal: " + sinal )


    }
```

Comment: Qual é o formato desses numeros `480 - 475 + 470 - 465`? é uma string? array?

Comment: sao numeros inteiros normais

Comment: Mas tens os numeros assim: `var numeros = '480 - 475 + 470 - 465';` ou assim: `var numeros = [480, -475, 470, -465];`?

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem seria algo assim:

```js
for (let numerador = 480, denominador = 10; denominador < 41; numerador -= 5, denominador++) {
    console.log((denominador % 2 == 0 ? "+" : "-") + numerador);
    console.log("----");
    console.log(" " + denominador);
    console.log("\n");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/PrintFraction.js).

Não sei se deveria ter esse sinal ou se precisa ser algo diferente porque a pergunta não tem o enunciado de forma clara.

Simplifiquei usando o `for` do jeito que ele foi concebido e não do jeito "receita de bolo" que todo mundo usa. Eu preferi usar duas variáveis para não ficar muito diferente mas o ideal seria ter uma só e a outra ser calculada em passo, por exemplo o denominador é só o inicio dela menos 5 vezes o resultado do numerador menos 10.

Simplifiquei o uso do sinal calculando porque o positivo ocorre nos pares. E aí um operador condicional já basta para decidir qual sinal deve ser impresso, inclusive coloquei o sinal em vez de escrever por extenso qual é o sinal, até porque isso não parece fazer sentido.

Se quer desenhar uma fração o ideal é uma mecanismo mais sofisticado para isto, mas podemos simular algo próximo no console de forma simples apenas observando como fazemos no papel e reproduzir aqui, então coloca o numerador (com o sinal, pode ser que prefira não por nada se for positivo), na linha de baixo a barra que faz a divisão da fração, embaixo o denominador. Dá pra formatar ainda mais, acho que agora já tem um parâmetro de como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é implementar uma classe no JavaScript que represente uma fração. Na classe você pode implementar métodos para somar duas frações e para formatar a fração quando exibida.

Por exemplo:

```js
class Fraction {
  constructor(numerator, denominator) {
    this.numerator = numerator
    this.denominator = denominator
  }

  get value() {
    return this.numerator / this.denominator
  }

  add(other) {
    const numerator = this.numerator * other.denominator + this.denominator * other.numerator
    const denominator = this.denominator * other.denominator

    // Implemente uma função que calcule o MDC e use-a aqui...
    const MDC = mdc(numerator, denominator)

    return new Fraction(numerator/MDC, denominator/MDC)
  }

  toString() {
    return `${this.numerator}/${this.denominator}`
  }
}
```

Assim, para criar uma função, você faz:

```js
const a = new Fraction(480, 10)  // 480/10
const b = new Fraction(-475, 11)  // -475/11
```

Para somar as duas, basta utilizar o método `add`.

```js
const result = a.add(b)
```

> **Nota:** como a adição é uma operação matemática que possui a propriedade de comutatividade, também é possível fazer `b.add(a)` e obter exatamente o mesmo resultado.

Ao fazer `` console.log(`Resultado ${result} (= ${result.value})`) `` a saída seria `Resultado 53/11 (= 4.818181818181818)` indicando que o resultado da adição foi 4.8181... que pode ser representado pela fração irredutível 53/11.

Se não precisar que o resultado seja uma fração irredutível você pode ignorar o passo de calcular o MDC entre os valores.